# Revtex and doi package incompatibility

Tags: bibtex, formatting, citing, revtex

I'm using `revtex-4-2` to write my manuscript and want to include clickable links (doi) in my bibliography. If I use the `doi` package, I get an error (`LaTeX Error: Command \doi already defined.`) even though the compilation seems ok. How do I fix this? Here is my MWE (adapted from Overleaf template):

```
\documentclass[prb,floatfix,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{doi}

\begin{document}
\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{paper title}

\author{Ann Author}
\altaffiliation[Also at ]{Physics Department, XYZ University.}
\author{Second Author} 
\email{Second.Author@institution.edu}
\affiliation{Authors' institution and/or address}
\collaboration{MUSO Collaboration}
\author{Charlie Author}
\homepage{http://www.Second.institution.edu/~Charlie.Author}
\affiliation{Second institution and/or address}
\affiliation{Third institution, the second for Charlie Author}
\author{Delta Author}
\affiliation{Authors' institution and/or address}
\collaboration{CLEO Collaboration}

\begin{abstract}
This is my abstract. This is a useful reference \cite{mylabel}. 
\end{abstract}

\keywords{Suggested keywords}
\maketitle

\bibliography{myref}

\end{document}
```

and bibtex file

```
@PREAMBLE{
 "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}" 
 # "\providecommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1}%" 
}

@article{mylabel,
author = "J. Pleschiutschnig and O. Blaschko and W. Reichardt",
title = "Lattice dynamics of lutetium",
journal = "Phys. Rev. B",
volume = "41",
pages = "975",
year = "1990",
doi = "10.1103/PhysRevB.41.975",
}
```

Comment: If you remove `\usepackage{doi}` and insert `\usepackage{hyperref}` then revtex will insert links to the DOIs, is this sufficient?

Comment: thanks, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`revtex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex) itself has a built-in mechanism for inserting DOIs into bibliographies, as part of that it defines its own `\doi` macro which conflicts with the `\doi` macro that the [`doi`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doi) package defines, making the two packages incompatible.

As [`revtex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex) will already add DOI links in the bibliography simply omitting the [`doi`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/doi) package should be sufficient in most cases.